# OpsWorks for Chef Automate and Chef validator-key

Tags: chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I'd like to know if it is possible to retrieve a chef validator-key from OpsWorks for Chef Automate? The aws documentation that I could find only describes steps to register an instance with the OpsWorks chef server using AWS cli or chef knife. I want to avoid installing the aws cli utilities on non AWS instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the key (Chef Server never stores the private half of keys for security) but you should be able to reset the key or create a new validator client using `knife client` commands. The only thing special about the validator client is it has create permissions on the client container (which you can set up using `knife-acl`).

Comment: Thank you @coderanger. It did the trick. 

 `knife client list | grep validator` to find the validator client, and the get a new key
 `knife client reregister default-validator -f validaton.pem`